# assigning values to object with different values

Tags: java, type-conversion

i have a set of data sets formatted

```
elements-
ag,gold,320.0
h,hydrogen,gas
```

i have 2 classes metal and non metal. they share the same symbol and name classfields but have different classfields for property

eg. gold has mass of 320.0 and hydrogen is gas

i was wondering how i could assign each of them to appropriate classes.

this is what i have thought up so far.

after reading those values from file get them in to an array then check if value at[2] is string or double assign it to non metal if string and metal if double, but since its a string when read from file itll always assign it to nonmetal class. if i parse it to double, i dont know how that interacts. there probably would be an error since letters cant be converted to double is that right?

how would i solve this problem??

Comment: What do you plan on doing with this elemental data?  If you can tell us this, maybe someone can offer how to cope with the fact that each row in your source data may have different types of data.

Comment: im going to print out the object if the user choice is to print out non metal element then print out hydrogen only for this example@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Best would be to change the text file so that each row contains data in the same uniform format, such as a CSV file format, with the same type of data elements at each item in the row, leaving an item in the row empty if it has no meaningful value.

Comment: Otherwise if you have no choice in the format of the data, then you must know the rules that currently *are* in place (rules that you've not told us the details of yet), and use these rules to create a row parser that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing to double will work, you just need to use try-catch block. Example:

```
try{
    double d = Double.parseDouble(valuteAt[2]);
    // do what you want if it is double, for example
    Metal m = new Metal(..., d);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    // do what you want if it isn't double
    NonMetal m = new NonMetal(..., valueAt[2]);
    }
```